# Performing a relevance search on a RavenDb index (lucene) across all indexed fields

Tags: lucene, ravendb

Is it possible to execute a query (relevance search) in Lucene / RavenDb, where it would automatically search all fields in the index?

I have an index which has a lot of fields (40+), and I would like to search everywhere for it.  Also, some fields have boosting applied.

My ideal query would be simply

`red dog`

And this would return all the documents, ordered by relevance, which contain these keywords.

Is this possible, or would I have to add a manual field which includes all the terms found in the 40 fields?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a field that will include all the terms you want. 
See also the techniques outlined here: https://ayende.com/blog/153729/lazys-man-comprehensive-search-with-ravendb

```
public class Users_AllProperties : AbstractIndexCreationTask<User, Users_AllProperties.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }
    public Users_AllProperties()
    {
        Map = users =>
              from user in users
              select new
              {
                  Query = AsDocument(user).Select(x => x.Value)
              };
        Index(x=>x.Query, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```